# Merging two macro in "Workbook_Open"

Tags: excel, vba

I am completely new to macros with no other experience. I don't know how to merge the following two macros and meet some error.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu").Activate
End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.Visible = False
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

If anybody would be able to tell me how to do that. Any help will be great : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can only have one `Workbook_Open` event per book, which means you have two options:

1. Put all the relevant code in the `Workbook_Open` event (See @alowflyingpig's solution) **OR**
2. Create two (or more) macros. Your `Workbook_Open` will simply call another sub upon launch. You can then house any series of code on non-event procedures in any order you may like.

---

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Launch
End Sub
```

```
Sub Launch()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu").Activate
    Application.Visible = False
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

---

*Note that you can call as many subs as you like from your `Workbook_Open` event by simply stating the subs name*

Comment: thanks for your advice, I tried this!  i get the result.

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu").Activate
    Application.Visible = False
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```